# BEQ command - Assembly Language

Tags: operating-system, mips, cpu-architecture

In my computer architecture class, I have just been introduced to `BEQ` command with syntax of-

```
BEQ(ra, label, rc)
```

In the execution, the program counter is incremented, and stored in `rc`. But in one of the examples, the professor used `r31` as `rc`, and we know that the value of r31 (containing all zeros) can not be changed. So how one can use `r31` as the register to store the incremented program counter value.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `BEQ` is shorthand for Branch if Equal.  it does no increment, nor any storage.  Perhaps a more complete example than one line would be in order?

Comment: Why do you think `r31` can't be changed? There are few restrictions in hardware on what can be done with the registers.

Comment: That is what I was told! That r31 can not be changed, and it has 32 bit zeros (for x86).

Comment: Sounds like you're describing `r0` (commonly written as `$0` or `$zero`). `r31` on MIPS is the return address register (`$ra`), which doesn't have a fixed value.

Comment: @Michael Both Alpha and the new ARM AArch64 use r31 for the fixed zero register. (For some instructions in AArch64, the r31 encoding can indicate the stack pointer, which is separate from the GPRs.) It sounds like this is a strange ISA where BEQ is actually BEQAL (Branch if Equal And Link), especially strange as it is destructive of the second comparison operand.

Comment: Using the fixed zero register as a destination is commonly used to indicate that the register result is unneeded. This can be used to exploit a side effect of the instruction without wasting a register for an unused value. Conditional change of control flow in your BEQ(AL) is such a side effect. For SPARC, subtract and set condition codes with r0 as destination provides a comparison instruction. A load into the zero register can act as a prefetch (ISTR, at least one ISA made this non-faulting, slightly changing the semantics).

Comment: x86 has only 8 registers and x86_64 has 16, neither has the register r31

Comment: Would you please add the correct architecture? In MIPS the zero register is $0 or $zero, not r31 too

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24222787/revisions#spacer-55bbba1f-0869-4891-a60a-cfeeb4d982d0) indicates that Mike W added the MIPS tag. With a BEQAL instruction, it sounds like a custom ISA (or it could be that the OP was mistaken in thinking BEQ saves the NPC). The ISA doesn't seem to be important; the question seems to be about why one would use the zero register as a destination.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Exactly - that is what my question is!